# Convert sum to function

Tags: functions, summation

I need to convert $\sum_{i=0}^N \frac{C_1}{C_2+C_3i}$, to a function

$C_1$, $C_2$ and $C_3$ are constants.

I am interested in resulting function itself and method as well.

Comment: Like this: $\displaystyle f(N)=\sum_{k=0}^N \frac{C_1}{C_2+kC_3}$?

Comment: yes, exactly like that

Answer (score 1):

There is an answer to your question but the answer is extremely complex since $$\displaystyle f(N)=\sum_{k=0}^N \frac{C1}{C2+k C3}=\frac{\text{C1} \left(\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{\text{C2}}{\text{C3}}+n+1\right)-\psi
   ^{(0)}\left(\frac{\text{C2}}{\text{c3}}\right)\right)}{\text{C3}}$$ where appears the polygamma function

Comment: looks promising, but how to calculate polygamma function?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function. Have fun ! Cheers.